# variables in recursion get reset. Can someone explain how?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this question from Leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/count-good-nodes-in-binary-tree/

This is my solution:
I am not able to understand why is this recursion the count value from root.left node does not hold up when traversing the root.right . In my understanding I am

1. Checking if current node is good or not and updating count and list
2. Traversing the left node to update count
3. Above count should go into right node while traversing right node and update the count value but its not happening

Why is this not working. I know the correct solution just cant really understand how recursion resets my count variable

```
    /**
     * Definition for a binary tree node.
     * public class TreeNode {
     *     int val;
     *     TreeNode left;
     *     TreeNode right;
     *     TreeNode() {}
     *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
     *         this.val = val;
     *         this.left = left;
     *         this.right = right;
     *     }
     * }
     */
    class Solution {
        public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
            int count = 0;
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            TreeNode treeroot = root;
            preorderGoodNodes(root,list,count,treeroot);
            return count; 
        }
        
       public void  preorderGoodNodes(TreeNode root,List<Integer> list,int count,TreeNode treeroot)
       {
        
           if(root==null) // check if root is null
               return;
           
           // if current node is actual root of the tree then count ++ since root is always good
           //also add the root to the list
           if(treeroot ==root) 
           {
               count++;
               list.add(root.val);
           }
           else
               // if node is not the root then check if it is good or not by looking into the list
           {  
                   int flag = 0;
                   for(int x : list) //looking into the list
                   {
                       if(x>root.val)
                       {
                           flag = 1;
                           break;
                       }
    
                   }
    
                   if(flag==0) // if it is good count++
                           count++;
                       
               list.add(root.val); // weather good or not add to the list
    
           }
           
           List<Integer> rightlist = new ArrayList<>(list); 
           // make a copy of the list to send to right node 
           //because count and list from left tree should not effect right tree
           
           preorderGoodNodes(root.left,list,count,treeroot);
**// why does count reset after this line ??**
           preorderGoodNodes(root.right,rightlist,count,treeroot);
           
       }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? [Java is is pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). The called side cannot change the value of a primitive variable on the calling side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. Each answer helped me in my understanding. I was able to learn that the problem was not my understanding of the recussive calls but the fact that i was send variable by value and not by reference.

This code worked for me when i made int into int[] for count. Please bear in ming that the standard way to solve this is  by returning int instead of void

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
        int[] count = new int[1];
        count[0]=0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(root.val);
        TreeNode treeroot = root;
        preorderGoodNodes(root,list,count,treeroot);
        return count[0]; 
    }
    
   public void  preorderGoodNodes(TreeNode root,List<Integer> list,int[] count,TreeNode treeroot)
   {
    
       if(root==null) // check if root is null
           return;
       
       // if current node is actual root of the tree then count ++ since root is always good
       //also add the root to the list
       if(treeroot ==root) 
       {
           count[0]++;
           list.add(root.val);
       }
       else
           // if node is not the root then check if it is good or not by looking into the list
       {  
               int flag = 0;
               for(int x : list) //looking into the list
               {
                   if(x>root.val)
                   {
                       flag = 1;
                       break;
                   }

               }

               if(flag==0) // if it is good count++
                      count[0]++;
                   
           list.add(root.val); // weather good or not add to the list

       }
       
       List<Integer> rightlist = new ArrayList<>(list); 
       // make a copy of the list to send to right node 
       //because count and list from left tree should not effect right tree
       
       preorderGoodNodes(root.left,list,count,treeroot);
       preorderGoodNodes(root.right,rightlist,count,treeroot);
       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need "pass-by-reference" semantic you can use `AtomicInteger` or `int[]` of size `1` instead of `int`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question of the "*why*".

Answer (score 0):

Recursive calls of `preorderGoodNodes` won't see updates to the parameter `count`: it's basically a local variable. The value and any changes to it only live for as long as the current method invocation, and changes are not made when its value is passed to the recursive call.

But the method is currently `void`: instead of passing `count`, return it:

```
// No count parameter, return type now int
public int  preorderGoodNodes(TreeNode root,List<Integer> list,TreeNode treeroot) {
  int count = 0;

  // ...

  count++;

  // ...

  count += preorderGoodNodes(root.left,list,treeroot);
  count += preorderGoodNodes(root.right,rightlist,treeroot);

  return count;
}
```

Then, in your `goodNodes` method:

```
return preorderGoodNodes(root,list,treeroot);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    
    public int count(TreeNode root, int max){
        int sum = 0;
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        else if(max<=root.val){
            sum++;
            max = root.val;
        }
        
        sum+=count(root.left, max);
        sum+=count(root.right, max);
        return sum;
    }
    
    public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
        return (1+count(root.left, root.val)+count(root.right, root.val));
    }
}
```